# How make repository save synchronized with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have one method that first get the last id from my table by one type. 
then I set my bean with this number and save

```
  Long number = geradorProtocoloService.getNumero(protocolo.getTipo()    
  protocolo.setNumber(number);     
  protocolo = protocoloRepository.saveAndFlush(protocolo);
```

I put this code in a synchronized block

```
synchronized (this) {
  protocolo.setNumero(geradorProtocoloService.getNumero(protocolo.getTipo());
  protocolo = protocoloRepository.saveAndFlush(protocolo);
}
```

the method have more logic(save a file and etc) then return this to my user

but when I run my tests the he are catching a few times the same number (numero) I think that happens because the jpa don't commit my transaction when I execute saveAndFlush.

So how can I make everything in my synchronizes block be commited with jpa

tks

Comment: Is it in a service? Is the service annotated with `@Transactional`? I think you might have to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right in your analysis.

Normally transactions are controlled by `@Transactional` annotations. So if you extract your synchronized block in a method in a Spring Bean with a `@Transactional` annotation and call it from outside any transaction it will commit in the end.